# Aliens abduct mathematician, astronomer, woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, warfare, alien-abduction

Bits I remember about this SF movie which probably originated in late 50s / early 60s:

1. Humans are flying in a light, general aviation, high winged, single engine aircraft.
2. An alien in a flying saucer abducts the whole kit & kaboodle (plane & passengers).
3. Takes them to a secret terrestrial base
4. Eventually tells them that his computer is damaged and he needs their help to get back to his planet.
5. He needs an astronomer for planetary masses & other information.
6. He needs a mathematician to calculate trajectories and perform other calculations.
7. He needs the woman as eye candy, lol
8. They eventually make it back to the alien home planet which is under attack by its enemy.
9. The attacking aliens are bombarding the original alien's home planet with meteors / asteroids.

That's about all I remember.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137318/story-id-humanity-recruited-to-make-parts-for-an-intergalactic-war (about the novel on which the film is based)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This Island Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047577/) is the movie you seek.  You have given an excellent plot summation.

Here's a still showing the aircraft in the saucer's interior.

[image: the aircraft in the saucer's interior]

And you can view the whole film online here

Comment: And somehow I can't help but think of [Mystery Science Theater 3000: The Movie](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Science_Theater_3000:_The_Movie) and interocitors.